# how to explain this program to implement interface

Tags: go

https://play.golang.org/p/LHkVGzmC7N

look this source.

specilly this scrap:

```
bw := NewWriter(b)
w, ok := bw.wr.(io.ReaderFrom)
```

i dont understand b is bytes element，NewWrite() take a io.Writer。
and bw.wr.(io.ReaderFrom),how use is?

what's mean the ".(io.ReaderFrom)" 's function?

and

```
   fmt.Println(w.ReadFrom(s))
```

w is io.write,in io/io.go the ReadFrom(s) is interface.

```
type ReaderFrom interface {
    ReadFrom(r Reader) (n int64, err error)
}
```

how in this source can  implement this interface?

in this source ,i cant find anywhere to implement.

Comment: In this case, the ReadFrom method is implemented by bytes.Buffer, see [ReadFrom](https://golang.org/src/bytes/buffer.go?s=5754:5813#L150)

Answer (score 2):

It is a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

In your case it asserts that `w` is not nil and that the value stored in `w` is of interface `io.ReaderFrom`. `ok` is going to be `true` if it is, and `false` otherwise. This code doest not check `ok` variable because of the author's confidence it will be implementing  `io.ReaderFrom` interface.

Answer (score 0):

- `bytes.Buffer` implements `func (b *Buffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)`, so it is of type `io.Writer` and can serve as parameter to `func NewWriter(w io.Writer) *Writer`
- `bytes.Buffer` also implements `func (b *Buffer) ReadFrom(r io.Reader) (n int64, err error)`, so it is of type `io.ReadFrom`, which enables the call for `fmt.Println(w.ReadFrom(s))`
- as @akond mentioned `.(io.ReaderFrom)` is type assertion, and the expression `w, ok := bw.wr.(io.ReaderFrom)` asserts that the `wr` field of the `Writer` struct is also of type `io.ReaderFrom`

For further reading check [laws-of-reflection](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection), it refers to similar code.